# How to iterate twice using iterator method in scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

```
// iteratorFunc is Iterable[SomeClass]
val iterator1 = iteratorFunc.iterator

iterator1 foreach {
    ...
}


val iterator2 = iteratorFunc.iterator

iterator2 foreach {
   ...
}
```

The code inside `iterator1 foreach` is successfully done. But, iterator2 gives empty iterator.

Please help.

Comment: What is the type of `iteratorFunc`? You say `Iterable`, but I suspect that its `iterator` method is broken. Is it possible that `iterator1 eq iterator2`? Because then obviously there is the bug. Iterators are consume-once only.

Comment: @0__ you should write an answer for it, I think it's a bug of `iteratorFunc`,  too.

Answer (score 8):

You should [duplicate](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator@duplicate:(Iterator[A],Iterator[A])) it.

```
val (iterator1, iterator2) = iteratorFunc.iterator.duplicate
```